# appscript - get multiple selected rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If i mark and select 5 rows in google sheet. I want to retrieve an array of retrieved rows. Particully column (0).

```
function selectRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowIndex = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  return rowValues;
}
```

But how to retrieve of all selected rows if I select multiple ?

Edit: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A single active range

```
function getData() {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues()))
}
```

#### Multiple non overlapping selections

```
function getData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let a = sh.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().map(r => r.getValues());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

#### In answer to your question

```
function getData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let a = sh.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().map(r => sh.getRange(r.getRow(),1,r.getHeight(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but obviously i didn't explained well. This will return if I select entire row
But what if i select like shown on image on Edit: